# use passed data before build method flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to access the information I've passed over from a previous class before the build method begins. But it's saying only static members can be accessed in initializers. I don't really want to use the static property, partially because I wouldn't know how to use it, but also because I think it seems unnecessary. In previous pages I've been able to access the data but only after the build method, does anyone know how I can access it before? Thanks all

```
class FirstPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _FirstPageState createState() => _FirstPageState();
}

class _FirstPageState extends State<FirstPage> {

  List<MyProvider> myList;

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

return Scaffold(

  body: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: myList.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {

            String imgPath = myList[index].image;
            String myTextPath = myList[index].name;
            String locationNamePath = myList[index].location;
            double distancePath = myList[index].distance;

            String myName = '${myTextPath} ''${locationNamePath}';

            return MyCard(
              locationText: locationNamePath,
              myText: myTextPath,
              assetImage: Image.network(imgPath),

              function: (){
                Provider.of<Data>(context, listen: false).addLogo(Image.network(imgPath));
                Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondPage(myName: myName,)));
              },
            );
          }),

    );

  }

}
```

My next page accesses the data using a key but it seems not to be able to use it before the build method, and that's what I need to get around!

```
class SecondPage extends StatefulWidget {

  final String myName;

  const SecondPage({Key key, this.myName})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SecondPageState createState() => _SecondPageState();
}



class _SecondPageState extends State<SecondPage> with TickerProviderStateMixin {

    final CollectionReference myItemsReference = Firestore.instance.collection('${widget.myName}');
    // This is where the error is

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

      return Scaffold();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `initState` method for anything related to initialization of `State`. See [this](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/initState.html) for more on `initState`.

Example:

```
CollectionReference myItemsReference;

@override
void initState() {
  myItemsReference = Firestore.instance.collection('${widget.myName}');
}
```

Comment: cheers my dude - i had a different problem but this still helped figure it out for me!